# Flash iOS Graphics Distorted

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am building an iOS and Android app in Flash CC using AIR 17.  It looks great when the publishing target is set to Flash Player 14, but when I make an iOS build it looks very pixelated and distorted.  Most of the graphics are vector.  I'm pretty new to mobile optimization in Flash, what are the best ways to make the graphics look as clear and crisp on mobile as they do on Flash Player?   I tried it with all the render settings in the dropdown but they all look like butt. :/

Comment: Are you using `renderMode=GPU`?

Comment: Use these settings to keep the app in the upper left corner and prevent it from being resized:  stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;